# How do I tell if a font is a symbol font?

Tags: winapi, fonts

Given an HFONT, how do I tell if it's a symbol font? A pdf library I'm using needs to treat symbol fonts differently, so I need a way to programatically tell if any given font is a symbol font or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [GetObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144904(VS.85).aspx) to get the font's properties to a [LOGFONT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145037(VS.85).aspx) structure. Check the lfCharSet member; if it's SYMBOL_CHARSET, you have a symbol font.

Comment: Dayum! I was just reading the LOGFONT page at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145037%28v=VS.85%29.aspx and you beat me to the answer...

Comment: This will probably be right in practice, but in theory it could fail.  GetObject returns a copy of the LOGFONT that was used to specify the font.  But the font mapper could have substituted a different font.  While it seems extremely unlikely that it would sub a symbol font for a textual font (or vice versa), it could happen in theory.  So you might be better off checking the tmCharSet field in the TEXTMETRIC returned by GetTextMetrics, as that should represent the actual font rather than the logical font.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy I thought that `GetObject` returns a `LOGFONT` of the font that was actually selected, not the one that was requested originally; it might be worth an experiment to verify, unless you have a corroborating link. If you think `GetTextMetrics` is better, another answer would be welcome.

Comment: @Mark Ranson: The font mapping happens when the HFONT is selected into the DC, because it depends on device specifics.  Since GetObject uses only the HFONT and has no information about which DC it has been or will be selected into, it can't return anything but the original LOGFONT. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7193439/1386054

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy it seems I've already seen and upvoted that link in the past, but thanks for reminding me because obviously I'd forgotten that useful information. You really should leave your own answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Mark Ransom's answer is going to work 99.999% of the time, but there's a theoretical possibility that it could give the wrong answer.

To avoid this possibility, you should use `GetTextMetrics` to get the `TEXTMETRICS` of the actual font and check if the `tmCharSet` is `SYMBOL_CHARSET`.

What's the difference between checking `lfCharSet` and `tmCharSet`?

When you create an `HFONT`, Windows makes an internal copy of the `LOGFONT`.  It describes the font you want, which could be different than the font you get.

When you select the `HFONT` into a device (or information) context, the font mapper finds the actual font that best matches the `LOGFONT` associated with that `HFONT`.  The best match, however, might not be an exact match.  So when you need to find out something about the actual font, you should take care to query the `HDC` rather than the `HFONT`.

If you query the `HFONT` with `GetObject`, you just get the original `LOGFONT` back.  `GetObject` doesn't tell you anything about the actual font because it doesn't know what actual font the font mapper chose (or will choose).

APIs that ask about the font selected into a particular DC, like `GetTextMetrics`, `GetTextFace`, etc., will give you information about the actual font.

For this problem, Mark's answer (using `GetObject`) is probably always going to work, because the odds of the font mapper choosing a symbol font when you want a textual font (or vice versa) are minuscule.  In general, though, when you want to know something about the actual font, find a way to ask the `HDC`.